# きっぱし = "absolutely not"?

Tags: words, slang, anime

In Akatsuki no Yona (a shojo series), H-kun is part of Y-chan's group (protecting her as a bodyguard of sorts). J-kun wants H-kun to join his crew.

Y-chan says "I want to meet with your captain." J-kun responds "なぜ？ H-kunをくれるの？" (Why? Are you giving us H-kun?). And Y-chan responds "ううん。あげない。" (No, I'm not), and on top of her, the extra characters "きっぱし" are added on, which the subs translate as "Absolutely Not".

[image: Y-chan with kippashi above her]

My question is: why is kippashi translated as "absolutely not"? The [only definition I see](https://jisho.org/search/kippashi) for it is "the remains of something after being cut up; fragments". Is this some kind of slang like "his hopes were left in shambles"? Or is there another definition I'm not finding?

Answer (score 3):

I just realized the answer. I've heard やっぱし before as a silly slang way of saying やっぱり. Turns out, this is the same thing. きっぱし is just a cute slangy way of saying [きっぱり](https://jisho.org/search/kippari) ("clearly; plainly; distinctly; decisively; flatly; definitely; resolutely")

Comment: +1, but it's not really a "cute" version of きっぱり. It's just a colloquial nonstandard variant. I found an interesting article [here](https://all-for-nothing.com/entry/2021/06/18/010252).